# How to write an immediate function invocation in Java? JavaScript example provided

Tags: javascript, lambda, java-8

How to convert the below JavaScript example to corresponding code in Java 8 with lambda. I am trying to get the Java 8 lambda.
Made up example.

```
// js
var isFlag = true,
    name = (function () {
        if (isFlag) return "A";
        else return "B";
    })();
console.log(name);

//outputs: A
```

I have tried writing it in Java 8, but the syntax or something is wrong. See the below code.

```
// LambdaTest.java
class LambdaTest {
    public LambdaTest() {
        boolean isFlag = true;
        String name = () -> { //I know this is wrong. It is not an IIFE. But how to write one?
            if (isFlag) return "A";
            else return "B";
        };
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        LambdaTest lt = new LambdaTest();
    }
}

// outputs:
// LambdaTest.java:4: error: incompatible types: String is not a functional interface
//        String name = () -> {
//                      ^
// 1 error
```

Thanks.

Comment: Stuart Marks's answer is the best literal translation of this JavaScript into Java 8, but I don't understand why you would want to do this. The reason people usually use IIFEs in JavaScript is because the language lacks proper lexical scoping, which Java has.

Comment: "I don't understand why you would want to do this": Nothing in particular, just wanted to know if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not java programmer but seems that something like this do the trick:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.lang.String;

class LambdaTest {
    public LambdaTest() {
        boolean isFlag = true;
        Callable<String> name = () -> {
            if (isFlag) return "A";
            else return "B";
        };  
        try {
            System.out.println(name.call());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //cause call can throw exception so we need to handle that
        }   
    }   
    public static void main(String... args) {
        LambdaTest lt = new LambdaTest();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide a "target type" for the lambda to be converted into an instance of a functional interface. If you don't want to declare a variable of that specific type, a cast will do the trick. Then, you call the method of the functional interface. In this case I'd recommend `Supplier`, which takes no arguments and returns type T. The abstract method of `Supplier` is `get()` so that's what you call.

Try this:

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

class LambdaTest {
    public LambdaTest() {
        boolean isFlag = true;
        String name = ((Supplier<String>) () -> {
            if (isFlag) return "A";
            else return "B";
        }).get();
        System.out.println(name);
    }
    public static void main(String... args) {
        LambdaTest lt = new LambdaTest();
    }
}
```

(Tested with JDK8 early access build 73, from mid-Jan 2013.)

Answer (score 1):

```
String name = ((Supplier<String>) () -> isFlag ? "A" : "B").get();
```

Not sure if this is performatic, though.